# how to configure dynamic linking of libxml2?

Tags: c++

I don't want to look stupid, but how should I link libxml2 to my g++ project (Linux environment)? What should I add to my code besides `#include <libxml/tree.h>`? Thanks for a link or a quick hint!

ps. I added this to my `CXXFLAGS`: `xml2-config —cflags --libs`. Enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CXXFLAGS are for the compiler, LDFLAGS for the linker.

So add

```
xml2-config --libs
```

to your LDFLAGS

and

```
xml2-config --cflags
```

to your CXXFLAGS